# Spring annotation for Reactor.receive

Tags: spring-annotations, reactor

I am working on Spring Reactor to write REST Services. I was wondering if there is an annotation to         `Reactor.receive` method like we have `@Selector` and `@ReplyTo`

Such that :

```
in.consume(req -> reactor.sendAndReceive("test.httprequests", Event.wrap(req.getUri()), (Event<String>ev) -> {
```

invokes the annotated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just return a value from the method you annotate with `@Selector` to handle `test.httprequests` events. The wiring bean should treat that method the same as a `receive`, which is actually just an alias for being aware of the `replyTo`.

Comment: Ah Thanks @Jon, Empty `@ReplyTo` was key for me, what I was not able to figure was how to send reply to anonymous `selector` set by `sendAndReceive`

Comment: The `@ReplyTo` supports a SpEL expression but unfortunately, we don't put the incoming `Event` into the `EvaluationContext`. Maybe what we need to do is just make the parameters available in an expression and they you could do something like `@ReplyTo("#arg0.replyTo")`.